# How to add buttons on sidemenu on top and bottom?

Tags: codenameone, border-layout

[image]I want to add `two` buttons on side menu . `One` at *top* and `other` at *bottom* so I have added below `code` but *its not working and its displayed image is added* . 
how to add buttons on `sidemenu` on `top` and `bottom` ?

[image]

```
Toolbar addToolbar(Form f) {


    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();

        f.setToolbar(toolbar);

        Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,new Button(" north"));
        container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,new Button(" south"));
        toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(container);

    }


void addToolbars(Form fs) {
        Form f = new Form(" Test");
        Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();

        f.setToolbar(toolbar);

        Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new Button(" north"));
        container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Button("center"));
        container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Button(" south"));
        toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(container);

        Container mySideMenuContainer = new Container() {
            @Override
            public void initComponent() {

                getParent().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                getParent().setScrollableY(false);
                getParent().revalidate();
            }
        };
        mySideMenuContainer.addComponent(container);
        toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(mySideMenuContainer);
        f.show();
    }
```

the container contains only half of screen as shown in image

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that and it's not supported.

However, like anything in [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) you can sometimes hack things together.

E.g. something like this should work as a hack although I can't guarantee it will work forever as it relies on implementation details of the `addComponentToSideMenu` method:

```
Container mySideMenuContainer = createSideMenuContainer() {
     @Override
     public void initComponent() {
        Container p = getParent();
        if(!(p.getLayout() instanceof BorderLayout)) {
            Component[] cmp = new Component[p.getComponentCount()];
            for(int iter = 0 ; iter < cmp.length ; iter++) {
               cmp[iter] = p.getComponentAt(iter);
            }
            p.removeAll();
            p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            if(cmp.length == 1) {
               p.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cmp[0]);
            } else {
               p.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, cmp[0]);
               p.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cmp[1]);
            }
            p.revalidate();
        }
     }
};
toolbar.addComponentToSideMenu(mySideMenuContainer);
```

Comment: it shows java.lang.NullPointerException at this line
mySideMenuContainer.getParent().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

Comment: OK I see a problem, fixed the code to make the hack more "hackish"

Comment: I have used this new codes and its whole code is added above question with its screenshot . It just covers half of screen how to cover whole height of screen?

Comment: This keeps getting harder ;-) OK, I fixed the code to account with the case of the status bar component